# Relationship between Cross-cap and Grassman Manifold

Tags: grassmannian

My professor, said that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cap#/media/File:CrossCapTwoViews.PNG is a visualization of Grassmann Manifold of n=3,d=1. Can anyone help me understand this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G_{n,k} $ is defined to be the collection of  $k $-dimensional vector subspaces of  $\mathbb R^n $.  The case $G {3,1} $ is lines in $\mathbb R^3$.  There must be a diffeomorphism between  $G {3,1} $ and the cross-cap.

The space is in fact  $\mathbb  RP^2$,the *real projective plane*.  See [Möbius strip description](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) . ..

(It's the sphere with antipodal points identified. ..)

Here's a reference I came [across](http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Cross-cap).

Comment: Thank you. Yes I understand that It is a collection of lines in R^3. How is that related to cross-cap is where I am struck it. Thank you for the inputs though